# Windows Process/Tasks over wmic?

Tags: windows, task-manager, wmic

There is a way to get the list of all running process/taks on Windows using the wmic interface? Is there is another way other than the windows task manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might have more information than you want, but this does return that information.

> wmic process get *

I suggest adding this to the command `>c:\temp\process.doc` and open it in Word with the orientation set to landscape.

Here are others that retrieve a bit less data, so pick the one you want:

> WMIC PROCESS GET name, processid
>
> WMIC PROCESS GET name,processid /VALUE